# How to use a different layout in Actionmailer messages?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, actionmailer

I have project_mailer with layout but I want to use different method if the project_notification method has parameter that `unsubscribe_link = true`.

```
layout "project_mail"

def project_notification(user, projects, unsubsribe_link = false)
  attachments.inline['logo_252.png'] = File.read(Rails.root + 'public/images/logo_252.png')
  @user = user
  @projects = projects

  mail(:to => user.email, :subject => "New Projects")
end
```

Comment: See http://house9.blogspot.com/2012/12/sending-email-with-rails-mailers-random.html you will need to specify the layout in the mail block

Answer (score 18):

I asume you already solved your question, I answer to help others:

```
layout 'project_mail'

def project_notification(user, projects, unsubscribe_link = false)
  attachments.inline['logo_252.png'] = File.read(Rails.root + 'public/images/logo_252.png')
  @user = user
  @projects = projects
  layout_name = unsubscribe_link ? 'other_fancy_layout' : 'project_mail'

  mail(to: user.email, subject: "New Projects") do |format|
    format.html { render layout: layout_name }
    format.text { render layout: layout_name }
  end
end
```

Comment: Would love a similar answer with [Devise::Mailer](http://stackoverflow.com/q/37779661/2832282)

Comment: @CyrilDuchon-Doris here you are: https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-Create-custom-layouts#application--devise-config