# setting erb template in Rails with mailgun-ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, actionmailer, mailgun

I would like to use the [mailgun-ruby](https://github.com/mailgun/mailgun-ruby/blob/master/docs/Messages.md) MessageBuilder API to build and send application emails in my production environment. The documentation suggests that I do something like this:

```
def confirmation_instructions(record, token, opts={})
 mg_client = Mailgun::Client.new ENV['MAILGUN_API_KEY']
 mb_obj = Mailgun::MessageBuilder.new

 mb_obj.from("from@site.com", {"first" => "First", "last" => "Last"})
 mb_obj.add_recipient(:to, record.email)
 mb_obj.subject("Please confirm your account")
 mb_obj.body_html("<p>how would i pass the default confirmation_instructions erb template as an argument to this method?</p>")
 mg_client.send_message("mail.site.com", mb_obj)
end
```

The problem is, once I started using Mailgun, I also stopped using ActionMailer's default `mail()` syntax. This seems to prevent Rails from manually selecting the template that matches the method name.

My first thought is I need to select it manually. An answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15078692/how-to-use-a-different-layout-in-actionmailer-messages) says that I can change the template like this:

```
mail(to: user.email, subject: "New Projects") do |format|
 format.html { render layout: layout_name }
 format.text { render layout: layout_name }
end
```

But this syntax conflicts with what is expected by `mailgun-ruby`. I can't leave the body/text setting methods out, and if I do, it throws an error: `Mailgun::CommunicationError (400 Bad Request: Need at least one of 'text' or 'html' parameters specified)`.

In the first example above, how would I pass the proper layout to `body_html`? That is, without directly writing the html in as an argument?

---

Update: my `rake routes` for confirmations

```
new_user_confirmation    GET    /users/confirmation/new(.:format) users/confirmations#new
user_confirmation        GET    /users/confirmation(.:format) users/confirmations#show
                         POST   /users/confirmation(.:format) users/confirmations#create
update_user_confirmation PATCH  /users/confirmation(.:format) users/confirmations#update
```

Comment: Have you tried rendering a view and sending mailgun the string value? I believe you can simply do this by calling `render "view_file"`.

Comment: Calyxofheld have a look at my answer and let me know if it helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wow, so...Rails default `mail()` syntax *does* still work with Mailgun. I don't know why it was not at first attempt, but I think it had something to do with the fact that I had not set the **production.rb** config to `config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :mailgun`.

Answer (score 2):

Looking at the gem's issues, it looks like it is not supported.

The way to go is to use your preferred template engine and give the output to the `body_html`.

You're not telling it, but looking at the method name, I guess you're using the Devise gem, and you'd like to send its content.

Here is how to make it working (didn't try it):

```rb
def confirmation_instructions(record, token, opts={})
  email_html_body = ERB.new(File.read('devise/mailer/confirmation_instructions.html.erb'))
                       .result_with_hash(
                         email: current_user.email,
                         resource: resource,
                         token: @token
                       )

  # ...
  mb_obj.body_html(email_html_body)
  # ...
end
```

Comment: you are correct! i am using Devise. this seems like a step in the right direction, but i'm getting an `Errno::ENOENT (No such file or directory @ rb_sysopen - /app/views/users/mailer/confirmation_instructions.html.erb):` error. instead of doing exactly what you did, i wrote `mbj.body_html = ERB.new(File.read(Rails.root + 'views/users/mailer/confirmation_instructions.html.erb'))`

Comment: So you should [export the Devise views](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise#configuring-views) so that they'll be present in your `app/views/devise` folder and you'll be able to load them using the same technic as you did, like: `ERB.new(File.read(Rails.root.join('app', 'views', 'devise', 'confirmations', 'new.html.erb')))`

Comment: again, a step in the right direction! however, i'm now getting `NoMethodError (undefined method 'confirmation_url' for main:Object)` when ActiveJob tries to send it. `confirmation_url` worked just fine in development. i wonder what could be causing this?

Comment: Have you tried to restart your server and the background job process (Sidekiq or Rescue)?

Comment: If the restart doesn't work, have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7461332/rails3-devise-undefined-method-confirmation-url

Comment: i restarted the server and dyno, but neither has had any impact. the stack trace begins on this line: `body = ERB.new(File.read(...etc...))`

Comment: Okay so can you please update your question with the output of `bundle exec rake routes` please?

Comment: I updated my question with the result of `rake routes`. Does the route even matter? `confirmation_url` is a default route supplied by Devise. i can't use `_path` since path is relative

Comment: Of course they matter :). Rails is providing `_path` but also `_url`, that's why you have `confirmation_url` in Devise. Look ! It's not `confirmation_url` but `user_confirmation_url`. Try to change that in the `app/views/devise/confirmations/new.html.erb` file and give it a try.

Comment: :( same error, but now it's `NoMethodError (undefined method 'user_confirmation_url' for main:Object)`

Comment: Okay then we need to pass the route, to the template, as an argument to `result_with_hash`. Please add `user_confirmation_url: user_confirmation_url` to the list of parameters of `result_with_hash` and try again.